# Static friction and kinetic friction

Tags: energy, friction

[This question might seem to be a duplicate one. But this slightly different from the others since I am basically looking for a clarification whether any of the mentioned explanations are atleast nearly correct or not]

Why is limiting value of static friction greater than kinetic friction from an intuitive approach?

I have across two explanation. One of them only states that in case of sliding motion, the highs and lows of the surface of the object is not interlocked between the grooves of the road(or the surface on which it is sliding). This explanation seems quite hazy to me since I could not get it. Another one states that in case of static state the particles on the surface of the object form temporary bonds with the adjacent particles on the surface of the road. So a specifi amount of energy is required to break those bonds. Whereas in case of sliding there are no rooms for such bond formation. Hence no energy is required to break such bonds.

1st explanation did explain the fact but was not satisfactory enough. However the 2nd explanation seems to be nearly a correct one. So looking for clarification. I hope that I will be able to know a brief intuitive explanation about this topic if both of those explanations are wrong.

Would like to thank in advance for sparing some moments to go through this question.

Comment: "Interlocked" is an imprecise term. I think the two explanations are equivalent if by "interlocked" you mean "form a bond".

Comment: You may find the following statement from this site interesting http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/frict2.html#kin "When carefully standardized surfaces are used to measure the friction coefficients, the difference between static and kinetic coefficients tends to disappear, indicating that the difference may have to do with irregular surfaces, impurities, or other factors which can be frustratingly non-reproducible"

Comment: By the "interlocked" I meant that the grooves of the surface of the objecr might adjuct with that of the road in such a way that there remains barely any gap or any trough like structure

Comment: Consider the friction force between two pieces of sandpaper. (No grooves required.)